# pgfplotstable: How to use 'pgfplotstablename'

Tags: pgfplotstable

How can I use `\pgfplotstablename` in this case

`\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\of\TestTable` instead of `\TestTable`?

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
A   B
1   2
0   2
1   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
}\TestTable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
every head row/.style={output empty row},% no header 
% works  funny (with speech mark...)
columns/0/.style = {
string replace={0}{\pgfplotstablename\pgfplotsretval},
},
% works not
columns/1/.style = {
string replace={0}{%\pgfplotstablename % \pgfplotsretval
\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\of\TestTable %<-- use tablename here
\pgfplotsretval
}
},
]{\TestTable}


%Test:  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\TestTable \pgfplotsretval
%\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\of\TestTable \pgfplotsretval
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crossposting [my answer from TeXwelt.de](https://texwelt.de/wissen/fragen/23434/pgfplotstable-tablename-auslesen-und-verwenden/24156) below.

---

When I inspect the definition of `\pgfplotstablename` using `\show\pgfplotstablename`, then I find in the log

```
> \pgfplotstablename=macro:
->\TestTable .
```

That menas the `\pgfplotstablename` expands to `\TestTable` in one step.  Now we only have to find out how to force this one expansion step somehow.  This can be done either with `\edef` or in LuaTeX and starting with TeX Live 2019 using `\expanded`.

```
\expanded{%
  \noexpand\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\noexpand\of\expandafter\noexpand\pgfplotstablename
}%
```

The leading `\noexpand` in front of every macro inhibits expansion.  The construction `\expandafter\noexpand\pgfplotstablename` leads TeX to jump over `\noexpand` and expanding `\pgfplotstablename` once.  After that we have `\noexpand\TestTable` and all is good.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotstableread[header=false]{
A   B
1   2
0   2
1   0
0   2
0   2
1   0
}\TestTable

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[string type,
every head row/.style={output empty row},% keinen header anzeigen
% works  funny (with speech mark...)
columns/0/.style = {
  string replace={0}{\pgfplotstablename\pgfplotsretval},
},
% works not
columns/1/.style = {
  string replace={0}{%\pgfplotstablename % \pgfplotsretval
    \expanded{%
      \noexpand\pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\noexpand\of\expandafter\noexpand\pgfplotstablename
    }%
    \pgfplotsretval
  }
},
]{\TestTable}

% Test:  \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]0}\of\TestTable \pgfplotsretval
% \pgfplotstablegetelem{0}{[index]1}\of\TestTable \pgfplotsretval
\end{document}
```

[image]